# PHP: syntax error, unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW))

Tags: php, mysql, composer, slim

Estoy comenzando a incursionar en Php, trabajé por un tiempo en API Rest con Node, utilizando Restify y como validador a Joi y validate. Para BD trabajé con MongoDb y SQL Server.

Ahora en php, ya tengo implementado un CRUD muy básico, trabajando con SLIM, y MySql. Necesito implementar un validador, he leído en algunos post que Symfony sirve para esto.

En mi endpoint hago un llamado a la clase en donde tengo los validadores, en este caso ValidateCliente, y dentro de esta clase tengo una función validaCliente($input) que debería recibir como parametro las key del Request. Lamentablemente en la clase me figura un error.

> (syntax error, unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW)).

```
 require_once('src/helpers/validators/cliente/validate.php');

// POST Crear nuevo cliente  EndPoint
$app->post('/api/clientes/', function(Request $request, Response $response){

    $valid = new ValidateCliente;
    $valid = $valid->validaCliente("ljkadj");

    $nombre_cliente = $request->getParam('nombre_cliente');
    $apellido_cliente = $request->getParam('apellido_cliente');
    $edad_cliente = $request->getParam('edad_cliente');

    $sql = "INSERT INTO clientes (nombre_cliente, apellido_cliente, 
     edad_cliente) VALUES 
            (:nombre_cliente, :apellido_cliente, :edad_cliente)";
 try{
    $db = new BDConnect;
    $db = $db->connect();
    $resultado = $db->prepare($sql);

    $resultado->bindParam(':nombre_cliente', $nombre_cliente);
    $resultado->bindParam(':apellido_cliente', $apellido_cliente);
    $resultado->bindParam(':edad_cliente', $edad_cliente);


    $resultado->execute();
    echo json_encode("Nuevo cliente guardado.");  

    $resultado = null;
    $db = null;
    }catch(PDOException $e){
      echo '{"error" : {"text":'.$e->getMessage().'}';
    }
   });
```

Clase ValidateCliente en helpers

```
<?php
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Validation;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
$validator = Validation::createValidator();
$dataIn = '';

$groups = new Assert\GroupSequence(['Default', 'custom']);
class ValidateCliente{

    function validaCliente($input){
        $dataIn= $input;
        'nombre_cliente' => new Assert\Length(['min' => 102]), //Error 
          //syntax error, unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW)). 
        'apellido_cliente' => new Assert\Length(['max' => 50]),
        'edad_cliente' => new Assert\Type(['type' => 'int']),  

      }
        new CustomUniqueTagValidator(['groups' => 'custom']),
  }
    $violations = $validator->validate($dataIn, $groups);
```

código github.
https://github.com/rvargassanhueza/apiRestFul_php_v1

Comment: Bienvenido, por favor lee [ask], las preguntas deberán de ser sobre dudas puntuales y no basadas en opiniones o sugerencias pues eso es motivo de cierre

Comment: oka, disculpa, seré más breve entonces. Muchas gracias por la acotación

Comment: La clase ValidateCliente que muestras está completamente rota. La línea del error `'nombre_cliente' => new Assert\Length(['min' => 102]),` y las dos siguientes son los elementos de un array pero falta el principio, debes haber borrado la línea. Las llaves de cierre tiene la línea `new CustomUniqueTagValidator(['groups' => 'custom']),` ahí en medio, sin sentido ninguno.

Comment: ok muchas gracias... encontré esto que de seguro va a ser de mucha ayuda.

https://gitnacho.github.io/symfony-docs-es/book/validation.html